# ARM Assembler on Raspberry Pi loading hexadecimals as constants if the hexadecimal contains a letter

Tags: assembly, arm, hex, raspberry-pi, gnu

I have a program that converts numbers into ASCII in GNU ARM assembler so it can be printed.

When I do `mov r0, #130`, the hexadecimal is 82 and it is printed after executing the rest of my code. I've also tried with `mov r0, #1280` and my program prints 500 which is also correct. `r0` is the input to my program basically.

Now when I try to do `mov r0, #230` or `mov r0, #330` it doesn't work correctly. The hexadecimals are E6 for #230 but i get B6 while hex 14A for #330 gets me an error. As we can see, these hexadecimals contain letters.I get an error that runs and says that it's loaded as a constant instead? Can anyone explain the theory behind this and give me clues to how to solve it?.

Error: invalid constant (14a) after fixup

```
 .data
tab:    .asciz "0123456789abcedf"

message: .space 200
message2: .space 200
message3: .space 200
.text
_start: 

@mov r0, #130
@ldr r11, =message
@bl print32bitar
mov r0, #130
ldr r11, =message2
b print32bitar
mov r0,#1
mov r7,#1
swi 0x0

print32bitar:
stmdb sp!,{r1-r10,r12}

mov r1, #0xf0000000
mov r2, #0
mov r3, #0
mov r4, #0
mov r6, #32
mov r5, #0
mov r7,#0
mov r9, #0
mov r8, r11
mov r10, #0
mov r12, #0

loop:
mov r3, #8
mov r5, r0
and r5, r1
sub r6, #4
lsr r5, r6
lsr r1, #4
add r4, #1

ldr r7, =tab
ldrb r9, [r7,r5]
cmp r12, #1
beq storeloop
cmp r9, #48
bne flagloop
b loop
storeloop:  
strb r9, [r8],#4
cmp r3,r4
bne loop

mov r0, #1
mov r1, r11
mov r2, #100
mov r7, #4
swi 0x0

ldmia sp!, {r1-r10,r12}

flagloop:
mov r12, #1
b storeloop
```

Comment: Show the exact soure code line(s), and the exact assembler output.

Comment: Immediates in ARM opcodes are on the form `ZeroExtend(imm8) ROR (imm4*2)`. 230 should work, but 330 shouldn't. By the way, 250 doesn't equal 0x82. Did you mean 130 instead of 250?

Comment: yeah sorry Michael, I meant 130!

Comment: unwind, I've added my code now

Comment: `mov r0, = #130` <-- what's that? Where in the code you're pasting are you using the immediate 330?

Comment: Ah, it should've been `mov r0, 130`. But yeah, in the code as you see in my `print32bitar`, I didn't stack the r0 or reset it so i'm using it there.

Comment: You said that using 130 works, so why is the code using 130? The code you put in your question should be the one needed to reproduce the problem you're having. As for why `mov r0,#330` doesn't work, see my first comment (330 cannot be represented by the formula given there).